# Reload Partial Template in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, refresh

I have a partial template called "LocationPicker.html" within my main-Template. In my controller there is a function, that should refresh the partial Template ("LocationPicker.html"), but leave the main Template.
I tried `$route.reload()`, but this refreshes the whole page, including the main-Template.

Is there a way i can tell the system, which template to reload? (I imagine something like `$route.reload("LocationPicker.html")`)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you wont need to refresh a template. All that you need to do  is to update your model and the UI will be updated accordingly.

May be you are using a wrong pattern?

Comment: Well, its rather complicated to explain. Within my partial Template "LocationPicker", i open a modal, wich the user is able to enter a new location. When submitting, the location is transferred into the database and i have to reload the "LocationPicker.html", so it catches the new entry from the database. But as the database-part is done by laravel it may be youre right. Maybe its never a good idea to combine two frameworks. But  anyway, is there no way to do it?

Comment: did you try :  $location.path(path of the partial template); ?

Comment: not sure how you are using it. I assume you are using ng-view?